# Learning Python 3.3 - TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: oop, python-3.3

I was trying to solve Challenge 2 at the end of the classes chapter (Chapter 8) in "Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner" which is stated as:

> Write a program that simulates a television by creating it as an object. The user should be able to enter a channel number and raise or lower the volume. Make sure that the channel number and the volume level stay within valid ranges.

I keep getting: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable, which at this stage just isn't very helpful.
I'm a beginner but I've seen something really similar working (see at the bottom right below my code) and nearly went as far as nearly copying that code. Could somebody maybe explain what's wrong with this and how I can get it to work?

Here's the complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 50, in main
    tv.channel(newchannel = int(input("What channel would you like to set the TV to?")))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

My code is below,

Thanks

```
class Television(object):
    """a TV"""
    def __init__(self, channel = 0, volume = 0):
        self.channel = channel
        self.volume = volume

    def channel(self, newchannel = 0):
        if newchannel <= 0 or newchannel >9:
            print("No negative numbers or numbers higher than 9. Start again from the menu")
        else:
            self.channel = newchannel
            print("You set the TV on channel", self.channel)

    def volume(self, newvolume = 0):
        if newvolume <= 0 or newvolume >9:
            print("No negative numbers or numbers higher than 9. Start again from the menu")
        else:
            self.volume = newvolume
            print("You set the TV on volume", self.volume)

    def watch(self):
        print("You are watching channel", self.channel, "at volume", self.volume)

def main():
    tv = Television()

choice = None  
while choice != "0":
    print \
    ("""
    TV

    0 - Quit
    1 - Watch the TV
    2 - Change channel
    3 - Set the volume
    """)

    choice = input("Choice: ")
    print()

    # exit
    if choice == "0":
        print("Good-bye.")

    elif choice == "1":
        tv.watching()

    elif choice == "2":
        tv.channel(newchannel = int(input("What channel would you like to set the TV to?")))

    elif choice == "3":
        tv.volume(newvolume = int(input("What channel would you like to set the TV to?")))

    # some unknown choice
    else:
        print("\nSorry, but", choice, "isn't a valid choice.")

main()
("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Why does the following work instead? To me, it looks pretty similar to what I've done.

```
class Critter(object):
    """A virtual pet"""
    def __init__(self, hunger = 0, boredom = 0):
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.boredom = boredom

    def eat(self, food = 4):
        print("Brruppp.  Thank you.")
        self.hunger += food
        if self.hunger < 0:
            self.hunger = 0


crit = Critter()
print(crit.hunger)
crit.eat(food = int(input("how much do you want to feed him?")))
print(crit.hunger)
```

Comment: does it tell you which line the error is coming from?

Comment: Of course, sorry.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 50, in main
    tv.channel(newchannel = int(input("What channel would you like to set the TV to?")))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are defining a method with the same name as a property. That is, you're saying `Television.channel` is an int, but later you are binding a method to that name.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.
I thought I could give a method and an attribute the same name since they use a different syntax. I.e. methods are called using brackets, attributes are set by means of assignment statements using an equal sign.

Comment: That's not actually true. A function is a callable object. You could assign a function to an attribute, and then you'd have an attribute that looks exactly like a method (that is, it can be called with parentheses). But anyway, as you learned from your question and this answer, Python doesn't use a separate namespace for methods vs attributes. Is there any reason not to accept my answer as correct?